# Subquery alternative for a function?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm trying to get a procedure that will get as parameters 2 varchars (1 for the first name, and 1 for the last name) and will return (if exists) the id of the manager with that name;

My employees table looks something like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
MANAGER_ID NUMBER
```

My function is right here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_test(v_fn employees.first_name%type,
                                    v_ln employees.last_name%type) RETURN NUMBER IS numar NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT e.employee_id INTO numar from
        employees e
        where e.last_name = v_ln and e.first_name = v_fn;
        IF numar IN (SELECT manager_id from employees)  /*here is the problem */
            THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('That is not a manager');
            ELSE return numar;
        END IF;
        return numar;
        end;
        /
```

When i run it i get this error `PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context`
Is there any alternative for this subquery that verifies if the id of the employee is actually an id of a manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a second query, such as a count of matching rows, and test that result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_test(v_fn employees.first_name%type,
                                    v_ln employees.last_name%type)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    numar NUMBER;
    manager_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT e.employee_id INTO numar from
    employees e
    where e.last_name = v_ln and e.first_name = v_fn;

    SELECT count(*) INTO manager_count from
    employees e
    where manager_id = numar;

    IF manager_count = 0
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('That is not a manager');
        ELSE return numar;
    END IF;
    return numar;
END;
/
```

Or within a single query you could use an outer join and count matching rows, or - I think a little more clearly, and potentially more efficiently (not really here, but in more complicated situation) test with `exists`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_test(v_fn employees.first_name%type,
                                    v_ln employees.last_name%type)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    numar NUMBER;
    is_manager VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
    SELECT e.employee_id,
        case when exists (
            select null from employees m where m.manager_id = e.employee_id
        ) then 'yes' else 'no' end
    INTO numar, is_manager from
    employees e
    where e.last_name = v_ln and e.first_name = v_fn;

    IF is_manager != 'yes'
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('That is not a manager');
        ELSE return numar;
    END IF;
    return numar;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3c5fd44a2eeef8ae2564c32b9b3014bc)

You should also decide how you want to handle the parameters you are passed not matching any rows. At the moment the query will throw "ORA-01403: no data found" in a PL/SQL context, or just return null in a SQL context, which may be fine.

It generally isn't safe to assume someone calling your function will be able to see anything you send through `dbms_output` (by default db<>fiddle doesn't show it for the SQL call, for example); and your `else` branch is a bit pointless since you return the `numar` value either way.

All of that is going rather out of scope of your actual question though.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Alex Poole’s answer, an alternative may be the following.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_test(v_fn employees.first_name%type,
                                    v_ln employees.last_name%type)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    numar NUMBER;
    manager_id employees.manager_id%type;
BEGIN
    with 
      "S" as
      ( select e.employee_id
             , m.manager_id
             , 1 srt
          from employees e
               left join employees m
                      on e.employee_id = m.employee_id
         where e.last_name      = v_ln
               and e.first_name = v_fn
               and rownum = 1
        union all
        select null
             , null
             , 2
          from dual
      )
      select employee_id
           , manager_id
        into numar
           , manager_id
        from "S"
       where rownum = 1
       order by srt
    ;
    
    if numar is null then
      dbms_output.put_line('That is not an employee');
    elsif manager_id is null then 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('That is not a manager');
    end if;
    
    return numar;
END;
/
```

**Edit**
Or, perhaps a more elegant solution is this refactored version.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_test(v_fn employees.first_name%type,
                                    v_ln employees.last_name%type)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    numar NUMBER;
    manager_id employees.manager_id%type;
BEGIN
    select e.employee_id
         , m.manager_id
      into numar
         , manager_id         
      from dual 
           left join employees e
                  on e.last_name      = v_ln
                     and e.first_name = v_fn
           left join employees m
                  on e.employee_id = m.employee_id
     where rownum = 1
    ;
    
    if numar is null then
      dbms_output.put_line('That is not an employee');
    elsif manager_id is null then 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('That is not a manager');
    end if;
    
    return numar;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee172a2a02f0ecc71067a26e117777e5)